# How do I send the logs from Graylog to an s3 Bucket?

Tags: graylog

I'm looking for an easy implementation to send the old logs from Graylog automatically to s3 to save disk space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Graylog offers archiving capabilities, using S3 compliant storage as a backend, in it's commercial offering. Graylog Ops or Graylog Security both offer this functionality and are available in self-managed or cloud-based platforms.

Comment: Is there any other way using the open source version? Thanks!

Comment: Well, that really depends on how much effort and time you have to put into it. Graylog has an open architecture and allows for custom plugins to add functionality. If you have coding resources, you could write a plugin that does archiving and storage using S3 storage. I'm not aware of any plugins publicly available that do it today.